# How to create a User with mongoose using HTML forms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forms, express, mongoose

I am writing a web application using MERN-stack. I already created my User schema using mongoose (schema and model), and used expressJS to set up the environment. I can connect to MongoDB, and I can also add new users by hardcoding it in the .js file (using `const newUser = new User({...})` and then `newUser.save()`). However, I am strugging with sending information from the form in my HTML file so that a user can create a new User entry in MongoDB (create an account). Whenever I click on submit, nothing happens, and nothing gets logged to the console.

As explained previously, I already tested the connection to MongoDB by hardcoding Users to add, and it worked (post, get, put and delete all work). However, nothing happens with the form. I provided the User schema if it is useful, at the end of the post. Here is my ejs file.

**HTML Form**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Load-In Road</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/api/user" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="">Username:</label>
            <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Express app Post**

```js
app.post("/api/user", (req, res) =>
{
  const user = new User(
    {
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      is_broker: req.body/is_broker,
    }
  );

  user.save()
  .then((result) =>
  {
    console.log("User created");
  })
  .catch((err) =>
  {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

**User schema**

```js
const userSchema = new Schema(
{
    username:
    {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Error: username is required"],
    unique: false
    },
    email:
    {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Error: email is required"],
    unique: true
    },
    password:
    {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Error: password is required"],
    unique: false
    },
    is_broker:
    {
    type: Boolean,
    required: [true, "Error: client type is required"],
    unique: false
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you post the Express main application file?

Answer (score 0):

Try supplying the full url in the html form action attribute. For example, if the server is listening on port 3000 of your machine: `http://localhost:3000/api/user`